# Using ES6 prototype method map rendered nothing in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Anything wrong with my map method?

```
var App = React.createClass({
   getInitialState(){
     return {
       items:[1,2,3]
     }
   },
   renderItem(){
     return(
       this.state.items.map((item,i))=>
         <li key={i}> {item} </li> 
     )
   },
   render(){
      return(
        <ul>
          {this.renderItem()}
        </ul>
      )
   }
})
```

Couldn't see anything rendered, checked the console, no error found.

Comment: `.map()` is array`s prototype method. Not a es6 function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a syntax problem:

```
this.state.items.map((item,i))=>
                             ^
```

Remove that close parenthesis, and place it beside the next close parenthesis:

```
return(
  this.state.items.map((item,i)=>
  <li key={i}> {item} </li> 
))
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to get rif of the extra `)` in the map parameters list

`this.state.items.map((item,i))=>`   to  `this.state.items.map((item,i)=>`

Secondly you need to add another  `)` to close the return statement

```js
var App = React.createClass({
   getInitialState(){
     return {
       items:[1,2,3]
     }
   },
   
   renderItem(){
     return(
       this.state.items.map((item,i)=>
         <li key={i}> {item} </li> 
     )
     )
   },
                                    
   
   render(){
      return(
        <ul>
          {this.renderItem()}
        </ul>
      )
   }
})
  
  


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, IMO it's cleaner this way

```
var App = React.createClass({
   getInitialState(){
   return {
     items:[1,2,3]
   }
   },
   renderItem(item, index){
   return(
      <li key={index}> {item} </li> 
   )
   },
   render(){
      return(
      <ul>
        {this.state.items.map(this.renderItem, this)}
      </ul>
      )
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
renderItem(){
  return(
   this.state.items.map((item,i)=> {
     return <li key={i}> {item} </li>;
   }
  )
},
```

problem is in `.map`, you have to place code in {} and `return`